# Python: sum with if statement

Tags: python

The next exercise from CodingBat:

> Given 2 ints, a and b, return their sum. However, sums in the range
>   10..19 inclusive, are forbidden, so in that case just return 20.
>
> sorta_sum(3, 4) → 7
>
> sorta_sum(9, 4) → 20
>
> sorta_sum(10, 11) → 21

Here's my answer:

```
def sorta_sum(a, b):
  if a + b == range(10, 20):
    return 20
  else:
    return a + b
```

They said when `a = 9` and `b = 4` it should return 20 but mine return 13.

How come my `if` statement didn't apply and the `else` statement did? 9+4 is 13 and in my `if` statement everything in range from 10 to 19 should return 20.

Comment: `if a+b == range(10, 20):` should be replaced by `if a+b in range(10, 20):`, because `range()` returns you a list of integers in this case.

Comment: Or more explicitly `if 10 <= a + b < 20:`

Comment: Thank you! damn I really need to work on my little things notice skills...

Comment: I would use the less than symbols for performance reasons

Comment: @cricket_007 does a few more symbols really make that much of a difference? I started recently in Python and if there is some bad habits I want to get rid of them as early as possible.

Comment: @cricket_007: You don't try to pre-optimize a single statement to something less readable unless you measured it is a bottleneck, and it definitely isn't in this case.

Comment: @VincentSavard I find it entirely readable. A linear search is less efficient than 2 boolean checks, that's all I'm saying

Comment: @cricket_007: `range.__contains__` is constant time, so it wouldn't be a linear search. That's why pre-optimization is bad, you start optimizing things you _think_ should be optimized when it actually has minimal or no impact on the performance. Always write a code in a readable way, and if you notice slowness, use a profiler.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you use `a+b == range(10,20)` instead of `a+b in range(10,20)`.

The `range(10,20)` means a list of all integers in the specified range (under python2, in python3 it's just an iterator yielding those integers). This means that `a+b` which is normally an integer will not equal `range(10,20)`.

To check this you could try `sorta_sum([10,11,12,13,14], [15,16,17,18,19])` which should return `20` since adding the lists would produce the list of integers in the range which should equal `range(10,20)`

Also note that your approach is inefficient since it will result in comparing the result in comparing the result to each of the integers in the range. Instead you should probably check for the range using `if 10 <= a+b < 20`, perhaps you should also avoid repeating the addition:

```
def sorta_sum(a, b):
  s = a+b
  if 10 <= s < 20:
    return 20
  else:
    return s
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, a Pythonic way to do so would be:

```
def sorta_sum(a, b):
    s = a + b
    return 20 if 10 <= s < 20 else s
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(10, 20)` actually produces a list of numbers, which the sum `a+b` will not equal, being a single number. You should instead check `if a+b in range(10,20):`, to see if `a+b` is contained within the list of numbers in that range.

Alternatively, check `if 10 <= a+b < 20:`, to see if `a+b` is between 10 and 20